# Data is not displayed in php

Tags: php, json

i recently learned php i'm new to php. Json data is not show. when i run this code on hosting server data is display but in localhost data is not show

```
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $newArray= array();
    include("include/db_connection.php");
    $sql="SELECT categories.n_id, n_title, n_desc, n_img_url, n_url from news INNER JOIN categories ON news.n_id=categories.n_id WHERE categories.c_name='Headlines' ORDER BY categories.n_id DESC LIMIT 3";
    $res=mysqli_query($connection,$sql) or die("Query Problame ".mysqli_error());

    if(mysqli_num_rows($res)>0){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            $newArray['articles'][]=$row;
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($newArray);
```

Comment: Does it show anything at all? Is the data in the local copy of the database exactly the same as what is on the hosting server?

Comment: does not show anything and database is same local and server

Comment: The call to `mysqli_error()` should have the database connection passed into it, this may help.

Comment: no it's not woking

Comment: Turn on error reporting. Something is likely failing but without errors turned on you wont' see it. `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: this is not working